How to detect Out-of-Bounds Access within Placement New Boundaries in C++?
#include <iostream>

struct mix {
  int64_t x[10];
};

int main() {
  int64_t* p = new int64_t[100];
  mix* px = new (p) mix;
  mix* py = new (p + 10) mix;
  px->x[12] = 104;
  std::cout << py->x[2] << std::endl;
  delete[] p;
}


In this code, px and py are created using placement new within the same allocated memory block. When accessing px->x[12], it exceeds the boundary of the mix object, but it is still within the bounds of the allocated memory block p.
Using -fsanitize=address, -fsanitize=undefined, and Valgrind does not report any errors for this out-of-bounds access within the placement new boundaries. I need a method to strictly detect such out-of-bounds access beyond the object boundaries set by placement new, even if it does not exceed the overall allocated memory block.
The solution must strictly check every out-of-bounds access. It is acceptable if the solution is slower, as long as it provides strict checking. No modifications to the source code should be required.

Pretty sure you're going to have to modify the source code to accomplish this.

operator[]  and assert.

@tkausl: ...or just place a std::array and use its .at.

"No modifications to the source code (...)" - why?

All of the tools that I'm aware of (of which memcheck I know best) cannot do this.
The problem is that placement new is non-allocating. Well, there are two problems really. The second is that your out-of-boundedness is bigger than your chunk size. As a rule tools don't handle that well, having redzones smaller than the chunks (otherwise the memory use overhead gets to be prohibitive).
If you change your code to be something like
#include <iostream>
#include "memcheck.h"

struct mix {
    int64_t x[10];
};

int main()
{
    int64_t* p = new int64_t[1000];
    // second argument is size of redzones
    // third argument means memory is uninitialized
    VALGRIND_CREATE_MEMPOOL(p, 10*sizeof(int64_t), false);
    // allow space for redzone before px
    mix* px = new (p+10) mix;
    VALGRIND_MEMPOOL_ALLOC(p, px, 10*sizeof(int64_t));
    // allow space for redzone after px and before py
    mix* py = new (p + 30) mix;
    VALGRIND_MEMPOOL_ALLOC(p, py, 10*sizeof(int64_t));
    px->x[12] = 104;
    std::cout << py->x[2] << std::endl;
    delete[] p;
    VALGRIND_DESTROY_MEMPOOL(p);
}

Then you will get something like
==712880== Invalid write of size 8
==712880==    at 0x40151B: main (so_placement_new.cpp:16)
==712880==  Address 0x53ea130 is 64 bytes before a block of size 80 client-defined
==712880==    at 0x40150C: main (so_placement_new.cpp:15)
==712880== 
==712880== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==712880==    at 0x4B655AC: std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::_M_insert_int<long>(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (locale_facets.tcc:892)
==712880==    by 0x4B72A39: put (locale_facets.h:2400)
==712880==    by 0x4B72A39: std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<long>(long) (ostream.tcc:78)
==712880==    by 0x401537: main (so_placement_new.cpp:17)
==712880== 
==712880== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==712880==    at 0x4B654BB: int std::__int_to_char<char, unsigned long>(char*, unsigned long, char const*, std::_Ios_Fmtflags, bool) (locale_facets.tcc:821)
==712880==    by 0x4B655D6: std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::_M_insert_int<long>(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (locale_facets.tcc:894)
==712880==    by 0x4B72A39: put (locale_facets.h:2400)
==712880==    by 0x4B72A39: std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<long>(long) (ostream.tcc:78)
==712880==    by 0x401537: main (so_placement_new.cpp:17)
==712880== 
==712880== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==712880==    at 0x4B654CD: int std::__int_to_char<char, unsigned long>(char*, unsigned long, char const*, std::_Ios_Fmtflags, bool) (locale_facets.tcc:824)
==712880==    by 0x4B655D6: std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::_M_insert_int<long>(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (locale_facets.tcc:894)
==712880==    by 0x4B72A39: put (locale_facets.h:2400)
==712880==    by 0x4B72A39: std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<long>(long) (ostream.tcc:78)
==712880==    by 0x401537: main (so_placement_new.cpp:17)
==712880== 
==712880== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==712880==    at 0x4B6560B: std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::_M_insert_int<long>(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (locale_facets.tcc:914)
==712880==    by 0x4B72A39: put (locale_facets.h:2400)
==712880==    by 0x4B72A39: std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<long>(long) (ostream.tcc:78)
==712880==    by 0x401537: main (so_placement_new.cpp:17)

I don't know ASAN so well. I'm not sure if it has any user memory pool mechanisms. You should be able to use ASAN_POISON_MEMORY_REGION (for p) and ASAN_UNPOISON_MEMORY_REGION (for px and py).


Using -fsanitize=address, -fsanitize=undefined, and Valgrind does not report any errors for this out-of-bounds access within the placement new boundaries. I need a method to strictly detect such out-of-bounds access beyond the object boundaries set by placement new, even if it does not exceed the overall allocated memory block.

To directly quote the requirement, you could write a custom checker on your own side. Here is a simple example to enforce logical object boundaries and verify that accesses stay within them.:
struct mix {
  int64_t x[10];
};

void* operator new(std::size_t size, void* ptr) {
    // Custom placement new (same as default)
    return ptr;
}

void* operator new(std::size_t size) {
  // Regular allocation
  return ::operator new(size);
}

int main() {
  int64_t* p = new int64_t[100];
  mix* px = new (p) mix;
  mix* py = new (p + 10) mix;

  // manually enforce bounds
  if (p + 22 >= p + 100) {
    std::cout << "out-of-bounds access!" << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }

  px->x[12] = 104;
  std::cout << py->x[2] << std::endl;

  delete[] p;
}

